# How does one recover Quicken data from a hard drive without the original computer?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, quicken

I have a hard drive with Windows XP and Quicken 2008 from an old computer that is not available. Naturally, this drive will not boot on the new hardware. However, I can access the files from the new Windows 7 machine that has Quicken 2010. Since I can't do an export from Quicken 2008, how do I make the files available for the Quicken 2010 setup?

**EDIT**: I have the old IDE drive installed as a second hard drive in the new machine to make moving the files easier. Its finding the specific Quicken files without being able to do an export from 2008 that is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking how to get the files off the old drive and on to the new one without booting from the old one, then the answer is to either install the drive in the new machine as a secondary drive, or to buy a cheap USB to IDE / SATA enclosure and gain access to the old files that way.  If you're asking how to find the specific files for Quicken 2008 once the old drive is loaded, I imagine the Quicken site might be able to tell you what the default file location is.  If you're asking how to convert the files to the new format, I don't see how Quicken 2008 could have an *Export* feature to a software version that didn't exist when it was written.  Most likely Quicken 2010 has an *Import* feature you will use.

Comment: Import from 2008 sounds like it should work.  I have one of the USB to IDE/SATA adapters and people borrow it from time to time to get data off an old hard drive and not have to install it or buy their own adapter.  Usually once they have the data the drive is no longer needed.

Comment: When you open Quicken, you can choose to open a Quicken file.  Point to the old data file and it will advise that it is an older version and offer to upgrade to the newer version on the fly.